# MySQL - получение минимального значения не равное нулю

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Появилась задача в которой нужно получить минимально значение но не равное нулю.

*К примеру:*

```
SELECT IF(MIN(`newprice`)>0, MIN(`newprice`), MIN(`price`)) AS `pricemin`, 
       IF(MAX(`newprice`)>MAX(`price`), MAX(`newprice`), MAX(`price`)) AS `pricemax` 
FROM `objects`
```

Но, в базе есть newprice со стандартным значением 0 - что значит новой цены нет.
И естественно запрос выводит pricemin = 0, а мне этого нужно избежать.

Помогите подпилить запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(if(newprice=0,NULL,newprice))
  from objects
```

Но может проще

```
select min(newprice)
  from objects
  where newprice!=0
```

А вообще в базах данных для обозначения факта отсутствия значения придуман NULL, его автоматически обходят функции min и max. Поэтому наиболее правильным, было бы хранить именно price=NULL, а не 0

А если именно допилить то что есть, то видимо как то так:

```
SELECT IF(min(if(newprice=0,NULL,newprice))<MIN(`price`),min(if(newprice=0,NULL,newprice)), MIN(`price`)) AS `pricemin`, 
       IF(MAX(`newprice`)>MAX(`price`), MAX(`newprice`), MAX(`price`)) AS `pricemax` 
FROM `objects`
```

Если я конечно правильно угадал что вам на самом деле надо